Am I Allowed To Run a USA LLC in Argentina while on a Student Visa?
I’m planning to move to Argentina to study for a bachelor’s degree, but I haven’t arrived yet. While I’m there, I was thinking about running an LLC business that doesn’t have any clients or connections to Argentina at all.
I came across this section in Argentina’s immigration law (Art. 51) that talks about work rights for residents:

ARTICLE 51. — The admitted or authorized foreigners as “permanent
residents” will be able to perform any gainful or profitable job or
activity, as self-employed or as an employee, being protected by the
corresponding law. The admitted or authorized foreigners as “temporary
residents” will be able to perform them only during the term of the
authorized stay.

I think students fall into the temporary resident category, which seems to mean we’re allowed to work during our stay, but I’m not 100% sure about this. Does anyone whether this means that in my case i am legally able to run the business while studying?
Also, is there any limit on how much I’d be allowed to work on my business(if i can work at all) while on a student visa? I’d really appreciate hearing from people with direct experience who’ve studied or worked in Argentina under similar circumstances.
Here’s the link to the law if it helps: Ley de Migraciones 25871, English version.
For your info guys i am from Algeria.
Thanks so much! 
